# Use Parse Path and Get Field Value for Output FC Name? Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

Is it possible to combine my parse path "value" and my get field value "date" to name my output feature class?

Essentially, I want the name to appear as such: "_40588_04102016"
So my output feature name is: %Value%_%Date%

When the tool is run, the output name appears as such: "_40588_1"

Can this be done?
If so, what am I doing wrong?

[image]